Degrees of freedom in mirror descent
The mirror descent algorithm makes certain choices which appear somewhat arbitrary, and so for each of them I am hoping for an understanding (maybe a proof) of why they are necessary, or at least some motivation for them over other options.
The following "degrees of freedom" may in fact be the same, but in accordance with the multiple interpretations of mirror descent, I will present them as separate.
1. Proximal viewpoint of mirror descent
A common motivation for mirror descent is that it generalizes the local regularizer used for ordinary gradient descent, in the following sense: the usual gradient descent update $x^+ = x - \eta \nabla f(x)$ is the solution to the optimization problem
$$ \arg \min_{x^+} \langle \nabla f(x), x^+ - x \rangle + \frac{1}{2 \eta} \|x^+ - x \|_2^2.$$
Mirror descent replaces $\|x^+ - x \|_2^2$ with a Bregman divergence. It makes sense that a different regularization might make more sense for different geometries/objective functions/feasible regions, but why must we restrict ourselves to a Bregman divergence? Could we use something like $\|x^+ - x \|_1^2$ instead?
2. Mirror map viewpoint of mirror descent
Another common motivation for mirror descent is something like "gradients live in the dual space and iterates live in the primal space so we shouldn't be add them," and instead we need a invertible map say $F : X \to X^\star$ ($X$ being the primal space, and $X^\star$ being the dual space) to convert between the two spaces. Sure, but then why does mirror descent only allow us to choose $F$ of the form $F = \nabla h$ (for strictly convex $h : X \to \mathbb{R}$)? Why can't we do
$$x^+ = F^{-1}(F(x) - \eta \nabla f(x) )$$
for general $F$?
(Obviously we "can" do either of these things. But is there any justification that they are not the right/best thing to do?)
